# Can I build only glibc malloc as a shared library?

Tags: malloc, linker-errors, glibc, relocation, fpic

I want to build glibc malloc as a shared library instead of it being part of libc.so

I'm not using any chroot but directly trying to build it.

When I make glibc as a normal build, it outputs the command that is being used to build malloc namely:

`gcc malloc.c -c -std=gnu99 -fgnu89-inline  -O2 -Wall -Winline -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -fmerge-all-constants -frounding-math -g -Wstrict-prototypes   -fPIC -DMORECORE_CLEARS=2       -I../include -I/home/sharath.g/glibc-2.20/build/malloc  -I/home/sharath.g/glibc-2.20/build  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/nptl  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux  -I../sysdeps/nptl  -I../sysdeps/pthread  -I../sysdeps/gnu  -I../sysdeps/unix/inet  -I../sysdeps/unix/sysv  -I../sysdeps/unix/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/unix  -I../sysdeps/posix  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/64  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86/fpu  -I../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch  -I../sysdeps/x86_64  -I../sysdeps/x86  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/ldbl-96  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32  -I../sysdeps/wordsize-64  -I../sysdeps/ieee754  -I../sysdeps/generic  -I.. -I../libio -I.   -D_LIBC_REENTRANT -include ../include/libc-symbols.h  -DPIC -DSHARED     -o /home/sharath.g/glibc-2.20/build/malloc/malloc.o -MD -MP -MF /home/sharath.g/glibc-2.20/build/malloc/malloc.os.dt -MT /home/sharath.g/glibc-2.20/build/malloc/malloc.os`

As you can see, malloc is built using `-fPIC` so I should be able to simply link it as a shared library.

However when I run this command

`gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libmalloc.so  -shared -lpthread -lm -lrt -o /home/sharath.g/glibc-2.20/build/malloc/libmalloc.so /home/sharath.g/glibc-2.20/build/malloc/malloc.o`

I get an error 

`` relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__libc_multiple_threads' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC ``

I don't understand why this error shows up? clearly I've compiled malloc.c with `-fPIC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why this error shows up?

The symbol is referenced by `malloc.o` via inline assembly, like so:

```
# 69 "../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.h"
#define __lll_trylock_asm "cmpl $0, __libc_multiple_threads(%%rip)\n\t" "je 0f\n\t" "lock; cmpxchgl %2, %1\n\t" "jmp 1f\n\t" "0:\tcmpxchgl %2, %1\n\t" "1:"
```

As such, it generates `R_X86_64_PC32` relocation (normal calls to external routines generate `R_X86_64_PLT32` relocations when compiled with `-fPIC`). This form of assembly assumes that the symbol will be defined in the same `ELF` image.

In the normal build, this symbol is defined as a hidden symbol (meaning it's defined inside `libc.so.6` and is not exported from it) in `nptl/libc_multiple_threads.c`.

Since you are *not* linking in `libc_multiple_threads.o` into your `libmalloc.so`, the symbol remains undefined, and the linker correctly complains: this symbol can't come from outside (wrong relocation for that) and isn't defined inside your `libmalloc.so`.

You might think that simply linking in `libc_mutiple_threads.os` would solve this, but you'll be wrong: your `libmalloc.so` would behave as if your process is single-threaded, regardless of whether it actually is or not.

TL;DR: what you are trying to do is unlikely to work, except by accident. It is *very* likely to be broken in multiple ways, some of which could be quite subtle.

Comment: Thank you. That was a very clear explanation. So there's no easy way to hack up a malloc.so ? Also for curiosity, how did you trace down the reference to `__libc_multiple_threads` that you posted in the answer?

Comment: @sha You certainly can build `malloc.so` using tcmalloc or jemalloc. But splitting out parts of glibc is not likely to work.